# Replace a space with a +

Tags: php, mysql, str-replace

Hi all Im haveing a small problem with MySql, basically I'm pulling in a variable from a table entitled addressone which is varchar 255! that thing I am trying to achieve is replace the space between the words with a + but for some reason it's not doing that! I have 2 pages one called path.php and another called thanks on my path I have this...

```
$notokinarray = array(' ');
$okinarray = array('+');

$addressone = $row["addressone"];
$addressone = str_replace($notokinarray, $okinarray, $addressone);
```

Then I have this in my html of that page

```
<select name="somesite" id="somesite">
<option value="">Please Choose</option>
<option value="yes">Yes</option>
<option value="no">No</option></select>
http://www.somesite.com/post.php?&field4=<?php echo '$addressone';?>
```

with a submit button that goes to thanks.php

on my thanks.php page I have this...

```
$somesite = $_POST['somesite']; 

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myMembers WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $addressone = $row["addressone"];
} 
if ($somesite == "yes") {
    $somesite = '<iframe src="http://www.somesite.com/post.php?&field4=<?php echo '$addressone';?> width="1" height="1"></iframe>';
    } else {
    $somesite = '';
    }

echo 
' . $somesite . '
http://www.somesite.com/post.php?&field4=<?php echo '$addressone';?>
exit();
?>
```

As far as I am concered all my spaces should be replaces with a + symbol but for some reason its not, can anyone help?

Regards, Phillip

UPDATE

I am going a different tact now and trying to place the + when a User registers but its still no good! check this out.....

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE myMembers SET field = REPLACE(field, ' ', '+'");
     $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO myMembers (title, firstname, lastname,username, gender, birthday, email, password, housenumber, addressone, addresstwo, county, city, country, postcode, phone, ipaddress, sign_up_date) 
     VALUES('$title','$firstname','$lastname','$username','$gender','$full_birthday','$email1','$db_password', '$housenumber','$addressone','$addresstwo', '$county', '$city', '$country','$postcode','$phone','$ipaddress', now())")  
     or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: why not use [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) ?

Answer (score 3):

Variables are not interpolated into strings delimited by single quotes. Besides, it is redundant to put it in a string if it is already a string. Just drop the quotes from around `echo $addressone` entirely.

That aside, [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) will correctly encode the string for you.

Comment: Can I seen an example please?

Comment: Noting that `urlencode` will also encode other chars as `%xx` it does not just act on spaces.